# Merging features in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgadmin-3

I am using PostGIS on pgAdmin3 (PostgreSQL 9.3 e PostGIS 2.2). 
I have a shapefile with more than 500.000 features and I want to merge them into one.

The geometries are MultiPolygon.

I would like to have as output a shapefile with the same geometry's complexity like the input. I Have to simply the geometry after a merge...

I used several codes but none of them seem to work.

All these queries do not return what I would aspect: I have a table with the same number of feature than before.

```
CREATE TABLE test1 AS 
    SELECT gid, fid, (ST_DUMP(geom)).geom AS geom FROM land_polygons;
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE test2 AS
SELECT
  1::INT as gid,
  ST_Buffer(ST_Collect(geom),0)::geometry(MultiPolygon,4326)
FROM
  land_polygons;
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE test3 AS
SELECT gid, fid, ST_GeometryN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NumGeometries(geom))) AS geom 
FROM land_polygons
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE test4 AS SELECT ST_Union(ST_SnapToGrid(geom,0.0001)) FROM land_polygons;
```

I do not know what I could do more...

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the geometry type of the features (point/line/polygon) and the geometry type of the desired result (your SQL suggests many different possibilities). If it's polygons with which you are working, what is the quality of the boundaries (to prevent massive numbers of splinter polygons)?

Comment: Please elaborate on what did not seem to work.  Was there an error or the result was not as expected?

Comment: The output is not the one I would.. I would like to reduce the features but their number is always the same

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate, but please do check out the referenced question as I think the answer will solve your problem as well.

Comment: Do not use unique identifier in the SELECT statement, just this:

SELECT  road_number,
  ST_Union(roads.wkb_geometry) as wkb_geometry
FROM  gis_data_highways_network.roads
GROUP BY road_number
ORDER BY road_number

This will sort of merge linear features (roads in my case) on values from column road_number